# replace nested substring using the stl

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

how would you (efficiently if possible) transform a string like

```
"class sfw::Smthing<class sfw::type<double>,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >"
```

to

```
"class sfw::Smthing<class sfw::type<...>,class std::basic_string<...> >"
```

in C++ using **at most** the stl?

Comment: [find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase), [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert). Get it right, then worry about efficiency.

Comment: What the C++ standard library needs to support this efficiently is a function template that is a combination of `remove_if()`, `replace_if()` and the (also hypothetical) `insert_if()`, and which also guarantees to visit input characters in sequence order. (It can *almost* be inferred that this last condition is guaranteed by `remove_if()` and `replace_if()`, since they require only a ForwardIterator and guarantee linear-time complexity, but they could theoretically be overloaded for RandomAccessIterators.)

Comment: Suppose this imaginary function template was called `list_transformer()`.  You would then call it, supplying a state-saving predicate function object that monitored the nesting level of `<` and `>` characters, and inserted `.` characters whenever the nesting level was greater than some `max_depth`.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, find and insert probably aren't necessary here, and they will likely make things much more complicated than necessary.  I'll add an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't do all the work for you, but I'll give you the basic idea.

Scan through the string with a for loop.  Keep track of what level of template argument you are at.  You can do that by counting up when you find a `'<'`, and counting down when you find `'>'`.

When you're inside the 2nd level (that is, the template arguments of the template arguments of the outer type) or deeper, replace the character.  Either replace it with a period, or, if you've placed 3 or more consecutive periods (another variable needed), replace it with a character which you know will not be anywhere else in the character set, like `'@'`.

Once you've done that, your string will look like this:

```
"class sfw::Smthing<class sfw::type<...@@@>,class std::basic_string<...@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@> >"
```

Then all you need to do is remove every '@':

```
str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '@'), str.end());
```